# Tokens in blocks configuration for List only pages

Tags: 7, blocks, tokens

I want to set a block to visible only for a certain path, with the logged in user id, like my-path/[user:uid].  I feel like I should be able to just do that.

How can I do this?

Comment: Or, if anyone can show me how to do this in preprocess or a hook, that would be great too.

Comment: First thing, you did not mention how you created the block or want to create the block. Second, by enabling php filter, you can set the path explicitly! Make sure the path 'my-path/[User:id]' exist on your site!

Comment: The block is a Superfish menu block, so I can't enable a code filter.  Also, the my-path/[User:id] does exist, but when the user is logged in, the path becomes my-path, so I need to cruch some logic to figure out if I can display my block.

Comment: detail blog: http://goo.gl/77zEds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with using [hook_block_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7).

For Example:

```
function YOURMODULE_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  global $user;
  $blocks['THE_MODULE']['THE_BLOCK']['pages'] = my-path/$user->uid;
}
```

Where THE_MODULE is the module defining the block you want to alter, and THE_BLOCK is the 'delta' of this block.

Answer (score 1):

1) Enable the core PHP filter module

2) Use **php** in the visibility setting of your block. Notice that the path 'mypath' must be registered somehow before using this code. I mean that if the path 'mypath' does not exist at all any code here will not work.

```
<?php
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid; // Get the logged in user id
// If the path is 'mypath/myarg' then arg(0) is 'mypath' and arg(1) is 'myarg'.
$show = (arg(0) == 'mypath') && (arg(1) == $uid); // It must return both TRUE

return $show;
?>
```

Alternative, use the [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.

Comment: I'm trying not to use the PHP filter.  Any ideas through a module or preprocess?

Comment: Why not use php? Template preprocess are using php also. If this block is made with views module you should use a user id argument for the block and then just use a path permission of 'mypath/*'.

Comment: PHP isn't the problem.  I shouldn't have to grab args off the URL for something that _should_ be simple.  I feel like there is a more appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add contextual filter: `Global: Null`

   provide default value: raw value from URL

   Path component: 1
2. Add contextual filter: `User: Uid`

   When the filter value IS available or a default is provided 
   Specify validation criteria -> Validator -> user

> Path validation (contextual filter: Global: Null)

You can validate the first path component in two ways:

**#1**

use contextual filter settings:

When the filter value IS available or a default is provided: 
Specify validation criteria -> Validator -> PHP Code

```
return ($argument == 'my-path') ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

**#2**

Alternatively, if you don't want to use PHP code validation in the contextual filter settings, you can use preprocess function in your `template.php` file. Not sure whether it's the right way or not, but works:

```
/**
 * Preprocess the primary theme implementation for a view.
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'YOUR-VIEW-NAME':
      if ($view->args[0] != 'my-path') $view->result = array();
      break;
  }
}
```

---

Assuming `'my-path'` it's the View or some other module custom path, in this case it has to be validated with the php. Of course if it would be an alias of some content type, then php validation wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a view.